# Why I never see the race result in my JCS phaser test

Tags: java, concurrency, java-memory-model

I am trying to understand how Phaser works and I wrote the following test with JCS:

```
@JCStressTest
@State
@Outcome(expect = ACCEPTABLE, desc = "ACCEPTABLE")
public class ConcurrencyTest {
    private final Phaser phaser = new Phaser(2);
    int a;
    int b;

    @Actor
    public void actor1() {
        phaser.register();
        System.out.println("Some action 1");
        phaser.arrive();
        if (phaser.getArrivedParties() == 2) {
            a = 1;
        }
    }

    @Actor
    public void actor2() {
        phaser.register();
        System.out.println("Some action");
        phaser.arrive();
        if (phaser.getArrivedParties() == 2) {
            b = 2;
        }
    }

    @Arbiter
    public void arbiter(II_Result result) {
        result.r1 = a;
        result.r2 = b;
    }
}
```

And to my surprise, I never see a race in the results (1, 2) only (1, 0) or (0, 2). Why is this happening?

The race appears if you remove System.out.println() from the actors and the JCS shows the result (1, 2)

Comment: I've tried it, and it is observable, but very unlikely (Win, OpenJDK 14)

Comment: @AndrewVershinin, thanks for the answer! On win 10 JDK 8 I never got this result

Answer (score 0):

> The race appears if you remove System.out.println() from the actors and the JCS shows the result (1, 2)

What do you think `println` does internally? Just open it up and see that it has a `synchronized(this)`; this prohibits many optimizations that could have been done : you are hitting this.